# Identify and append file extension to files using bash

Tags: bash, sed, mime-types

I have a folder with a number of objects. These objects do not have an extension in the filename.

I want to use `file` to get the mimetype and then rename the object as `object.mimetype`.

At the moment this is what I have saved as test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *;
do "EXT"==$(file "$i" --mime-type -b | sed 's#.*/##') 
combination= "$i.$EXT"
mv "$i" "$combination"

done
```

When I run test.sh on a directory I get output like:

```
test.sh: line 3: EXT==tiff: command not found
test.sh: line 4: CCITT_1.: command not found
mv: cannot move 'CCITT_1' to '': No such file or directory
test.sh: line 3: EXT==jpeg: command not found
test.sh: line 4: image.: command not found
mv: cannot move 'image' to '': No such file or directory
test.sh: line 3: EXT==pdf: command not found
test.sh: line 4: Job-Description.pdf.: command not found
mv: cannot move 'Job-Description.pdf' to '': No such file or directory
```

so I know that the `file ...` command works because I have tested it, but I am stumped on everything else. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be in how you are assigning variables. When you assign a value to a variable:

- The variable name should not be quoted – opposite case of when using `$` for parameter expansion of the variable
- There should only be one equal sign (the second equal sign would be considered as part of the string value)
- There should be no spaces on either side of the equals sign; otherwise, the variable name will be interpreted as a command name.

The following should do what you intend:

```
for i in *;
    do ext=$(file "$i" --mime-type -b | sed 's#.*/##')
    mv -v "$i" "$i.$ext"
done
```

Note: this code makes the same assumptions as your original code, i.e., that all files in the current directory (including any non-regular files such as directories) should be renamed – and that they will be renamed as per their MIME type so plain text files will have a `.plain` suffix.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to assign the output of `$(...)` to `$EXT`, for that you must use `=` instead of `==`, and you must not quote the variable name. With some other modifications:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *; do
    ext=$(file "$i" --mime-type -b | sed 's#.*/##')
    mv "$i" "$i.$ext"
done
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `mv -i` or `-n` for any bulk rename/move like this -- otherwise if there's a naming conflict, files can get silently overwritten.

Comment: What a pity you didn't post this 17 minutes ago. I just spent the past 15 minutes in my text editor and terminal coming up with almost the exact same answer. We both removed the `combination` variable and lower-cased the `ext` variable!

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Your explanation is more thorough, so it wasn't a waste of time! I was wondering how we ended up with an almost identical script, great minds think alike I guess. ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @alfunx, because you say that AnthonyGeoghegan's explanation is more thorough I am accepting his answer as the correct one, though obviously you both have the same script contents.